# Не получается удалить динамический массив

Tags: c++, delete

Не получается удалить динамический массив. Ошибка вылетает из-за delete[], без него нормально работает.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    string tvec;
    vector <string> myvec;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    getline(cin,tvec);
    myvec.push_back(tvec);
    }
    char *masvec=new char[myvec.size()+1];
    strcpy(masvec,myvec[0].c_str());
    strcat(masvec,myvec[1].c_str());
    cout<<endl<<endl<<masvec<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<myvec.size();i++) cout<<myvec[i]<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<myvec.size();
    delete [] masvec;
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените

```
char* masvec = new char[myvec.size()+ 1];
```

на

```
char* masvec = new char[myvec[0].size() + myvec[1].size() + 1];
```

чтобы копировать  первую введеннную  строку и выполнить  конкатенацию со  второй

Answer (score 1):

Методы strcpy(...) и strcat(...) предполагают что выходной буффер будет иметь достаточный размер, что бы поместить в него результат. У вас же используется:

```
char *masvec=new char[myvec.size()+1];
```

Т.е. размер masvec == 3 (ведь в myvec лежит только две строки). Уверен что результирующая строка у вас получается длиннее трех символов, что приводит к повреждению кучи. Ну а при вызове `delete[]` производится проверка кучи, которая обнаруживает повреждение, следовательно вы получаете ошибку.